# How to set expected exception in PHPUnit for incorrect file path in fopen()?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, phpunit

I know how to set an expected exception while unit testing using PHPUnit's `setExpectedException()` method and/or its equivalent annotation.

But for some reason I'm not able to do the same while testing some logic around a `fopen()` here is an example:

```
class AbstractFileReaderTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test_invalidFileException()
    {
        $filePath = 'incorrect/file/path.csv';

        $this->setExpectedException(\Exception::class);

        fopen($filePath, "r");
    }
}
```

Comment: fopen() doesn't throw an exception, it generates a warning (and returns a Boolean false).... unless you've overridden the PHP error handler to throw an exception instead of that normal behaviour

Comment: besides @MarkBaker's comment - setExpectedException's first argument should be a string.

Comment: Thanks both :), Chris \Exception::class is string ;)

Answer (score 2):

For unit test on file system it's better to use something like [vfsStream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/)

vfsStream is a stream wrapper for a virtual file system and for tests it's cleaner solution to write there then real file system.

Comment: Very interesting and useful tool, thanks. But is that alright to have [posix](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.posix.php) installed?